# CanvasJS (version 2.3.2) getting an unwanted line between first data point and last data point

Tags: canvasjs

I found an existing, similar question but the solution there will not resolve my issue.  My data is in sorted numeric order and without nulls.

The html file is almost the same was the CanvasJS line-chart-with-zoom-pan.html.  I've changed the title, put my own data points inside instead of using a random number generator and loaded canvasjs from the same directory as the html file.

Everything worked beautifully and was so simple! ... except for this extra line which doesn't show up on the example from CanvasJS.

Here is my html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>  
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
        animationEnabled: true,
        zoomEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: 'Problem with Final (Polyline?) Segment from Last Point to Origin' 
        },
        axisY :{
            includeZero:false
        },
        data: data  // initialized below
    });
    chart.render();
    }
    var limit = 6;
    var y = 0;
    var data = [];
    var dataSeries = { type: 'line' };
    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
        dataPoints.push({
            x: 3425,
            y: 33.979673769168
        });
        dataPoints.push({
            x: 6850,
            y: 36.27403787497398
        });
        dataPoints.push({
            x: 10275,
            y: 37.742500031440834
        });
        dataPoints.push({
            x: 13700,
            y: 36.02631567584654
        });
        dataPoints.push({
            x: 17125,
            y: 34.75456508773836
        });
        dataPoints.push({
            x: 20550,
            y: 35.236592156677126
        });
    }
    dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    data.push(dataSeries);               
    </script>
    <script src='./canvasjs.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='chartContainer' style='height: 370px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;'>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the original CanvasJS file that I started with and that works properly:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        zoomEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Try Zooming and Panning" 
        },
        axisY :{
            includeZero:false
        },
        data: data  // random generator below
    });
    chart.render();

    }

    var limit = 1000;

    var y = 0;
    var data = [];
    var dataSeries = { type: "line" };
    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
        y += (Math.random() * 10 - 5);
        dataPoints.push({
            x: i - limit / 2,
            y: y                
        });
    }
    dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    data.push(dataSeries);               

    </script>
    <script src="../../canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Indranil from CanvasJS for telling me what I did wrong!

There's a copy paste error here where 
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) { ... } 
is included and shouldn't be.  There's no need for a loop to plot the 6 points.  The looping is causing that extra line from the last to the first point.

So the final code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: 'Problem with Final (Polyline?) Segment from Last Point to Origin' 
    },
    axisY :{
        includeZero:false
    },
    data: data  // initialized below
});
chart.render();
}
var limit = 6;
var y = 0;
    var data = [];
var dataSeries = { type: 'line' };
var dataPoints = [];
DataPoints.push({
        x: 3425,
        y: 33.979673769168
});
DataPoints.push({
        x: 6850,
        y: 36.27403787497398
});
DataPoints.push({
        x: 10275,
        y: 37.742500031440834
});
DataPoints.push({
        x: 13700,
        y: 36.02631567584654
});
DataPoints.push({
        x: 17125,
        y: 34.75456508773836
});
DataPoints.push({
        x: 20550,
        y: 35.236592156677126
});
dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
data.push(dataSeries);               
</script>
<script src='./canvasjs.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='chartContainer' style='height: 370px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```